# Blue prism - Not able to Spy SAP GUI Screen element

Tags: sap-gui, blueprism

Trying to spy SAP system through Blue Prism for SAP Automation.
When I click Identify button from Blue Prism application modeller and move my mouse over to the T-Code textbox , then the text Box is highlighted using a red color box which says the TCode element is recognize by Blue Prism tool in SAP test system. however the same is NOT identified for SAP Production system.

We checked both SAP system has same settings maintained to enable SAP GUI Scripting.

Appreciate help!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it solves your specific problem, nevertheless:
**Pressing *alt* multiple times will change the spy method**, and you'll be able to find what you're looking for (even a method specifically for SAP).

Answer (score 0):

please check if the SAP Id of the item is the same in both systems. You can do it for example by identifying item in both systems. Please return with the answer what's the difference in ID between the systems.

Answer (score 0):

If you are starting out with SAP Automation in your organisation, you will probably not have GUI scripting enabled in the Production system, but it may be in the DEV system.

If you can access SAP then run RZ11 and enter `sapgui/user_scripting` then it will show a list of values, and the current value should be true.  Compare DEV and PRD.  You will probably need the SAP Basis admin to change this.

[Read this blog for more details](https://blogs.sap.com/2012/10/08/introduction-to-sap-gui-scripting/)

Andy

Answer (score 0):

For the best SAP automation performance with Blue Prism you need to enable both Client and Server scripting

i. Enabling Client-Side Scripting

- Start the SAP Logon and log in to the SAP server.
- Click the 'Customize Local Layout' toolbar button (ALT+F12).
- Click Options and in the GUI Options screen select the 'Accessibility and Scripting' node
- In the ‘Accessibility’ node ensure that the ‘Use Accessibility mode’ option is enabled.
- In the 'Scripting' node ensure that the ‘Enable scripting’ option is the only option set. Notifications must be switched off to prevent popups from blocking the spy mode.
- NOTE: If the options 'Notify when a script attaches to SAP GUI' check box and the 'Notify when a script opens a connection' are left checked then when you spy an element in the SAP interface you will see the message “A script is trying to attach to the GUI” every time you attempt to click on it. If you see the message “Scripting support is disabled by the user” then the ‘Enable scripting’ option has not been checked.
- Save the settings and restart the SAP GUI. The clientside settings have now been set.

ii. Enabling Server-Side Scripting

- Start the SAP Logon and log in to the SAP server.
- Run the ‘RZ11’ transaction (type ‘RZ11 ‘and click the green tick button)
- Type ‘sapgui/user_scripting’ in the Maintain Profile Parameters window.
- Click the ‘Display’ button
- Click ‘Change Value’ in the Display Profile Parameter Attributes window.
- Type ‘TRUE’ in the ‘New value’ field.
- Save the settings and log out from SAP Logon.
- Exit from the SAP Logon program (click the red cross button in the toolbar, or click the ‘X’ window button to close the window and the application). You may be prompted to save any unsaved changes, if you haven’t done so already.